# Is RSSetViewports call asynchronous or synchronous in Direct3D 11?

Tags: viewport, direct3d11

My application has to handle more than 20 view ports while only 16 are allowed. Thankfully, the whole scene can be divided in to several parts that won't "leak" vertices from one to another, each with view ports less then 10.

Now the problem is if it is good to change view ports array in the middle of rendering (though it is allowed). My guess is that as long as it is called **RS**SetViewports it should be asynchronous and could be called safely in the middle of rendering. But I couldn't find any proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes RSSetViewports is an ordinary graphics state command that is written down to the GPU command buffer to be executed asynchrounously, so there is no problem setting it many times per frame, it won't block the CPU on waiting for the GPU execution to finish.

No states do that, only explicit operations such as a Map call (without D3D11_MAP_FLAG_DO_NOT_WAIT) would block and wait for the GPU.